# File provider exception in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When i add a image to drawable resources, and i use it in a layout. When i run the application, Visual Studio prompts me an exception of unable to get provider xamarin.essentials.file.providers:java.lang.IllegalArgumentsException: Missing android.support

(1)Image error:
[file_provider_exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrtR6.png)

(2)My actual layout xml code:

[layout_xml_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxb2I.png)

Comment: Could you share a list of the packages in your Android project?

Comment: please do NOT post code and errors as images.  Take the time to include them as text and properly format them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Somewhere in your code, you are trying to allow users to upload files from their phone. The ImageView shouldn't be causing the problem, and the complete error message should say `Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data`

And in order to make that go away, you need to add this in your AndroidManifest file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```

Answer (score 2):

have you miss the configration in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="packagename.fileProvider"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true"
   android:exported="false">

   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```